# Bash - command works in console but not in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I have a command: `printf "\x$(printf %x $char)"`.
When I write in console: `char=65; printf "\x$(printf %x $char)";` the result is written letter `A`.
But when I run my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
char=65;
printf "\x$(printf %x $char)"
```

The result is written: `\x41`
I tried to write `sudo` before the command `printf` in the script and then the command works as expected. I need to find a solution without the need of using `sudo`.

Comment: Works for me. Copying your script above and executing me results in a "A", as expected. Things only change if you _remove_ the double quotes from the last line.

Comment: Are you sure that you execute your script using bash, and do not accidentally using some other shell (`sh script.sh` with `sh` not pointing to bash)?

Comment: You are probably running it with `sh script_path`, run it with `bash script_path`...

Comment: Using sudo just because some command doesn't work as expected is a *terryble idea*. You should use sudo only when you need to run something as a root.

Comment: I was using sh script_path and not bash scirpt_path - works with bash script_path. Thanks!

Comment: Since I was the first to hint you in that direction I allowed myself to post the resolution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

By running `sh script.sh` you [accidentally run your script using dash instead of bash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh), whose builtin `printf` does not support `\xHH` literals.